# How to put a txt file into a folder C programming

Tags: c

i need help with a program that creates a folder and inside of that filder a small txt file.
I have created a program that creates a folder but i don't know how to put a .txt file inside of tht folder.
Program must be same, it creates folder and txt file.
here is my code and what i have done

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dir.h>

#define SIZE 25      //Maximum Length of name of folder

void main() {
    int check;
    char *dirname;
    dirname=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter a directory path and name to be created (C:/name):");
    gets(dirname);
    check = mkdir(dirname);

    if (!check)
        printf("Directory created\n");

    else
    {
        printf("Unable to create directory\n");
        exit(1);
    }



    getch();
    system("dir/p");
    getch();
    }
```

Comment: You can search for "C open file". `fopen` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @bolov Yeah i know how to create a txt file, but how to save it in a specific folder.

Comment: You know how to create a file right? So create it in the folder you want. For the `filename` parameter of `fopen` include the path you want. E.g. `fopen("c:/name/file.txt", "w")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a functional code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dir.h>

#define SIZE 25      //Maximum Length of name of folder



int main()
{
    int check;
    char *dirname, *filename, *fulldir;
    FILE *fp;

    dirname=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
    filename=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
    fulldir=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter a directory path and name to be created (C:/name):");
    gets(dirname);
    check = mkdir(dirname);

    if (!check)
        printf("Directory created\n");

    else
    {
        printf("Unable to create directory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Gets filename
    printf("Enter a file name (filename.txt):");
    gets(filename);

    // Create full direction
    strcpy(fulldir, dirname);
    strcat(fulldir, "/");
    strcat(fulldir, filename);

    // Create file inside created folder
    if (fp = fopen(fulldir, "w") != NULL ) {
        printf("File created\n");

        // Close openned file
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        printf("Unable to create file\n");
    }

    // End function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you are the greatest <3

Comment: no problem, you are very helpful, i have just one more question:          How can i name .txt files automatically int the code, without program asking me to enter the name of .txt file.

Comment: In second `strcat ` replace `filename ` for one string like `"my file name.txt"`